# Search suggestions from different tables in different activities

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, searchview

Hi i have followed [official android guideline](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) for enabling search and search suggestions. I works very well but the problem is that it only search from one Database Table.

I have three tables and three Activities with the name `“BirthdayWisher_Table”`, `“Tasks_Table”`, `“Events_Table”` and `“BirthdayWisher_Activity”`, `“Tasks_Activity”`, `“Events_Activity”` respectively.

I want that when the user is in the “BirthdayWisher_Activity” and press the Search menu item my app should search data from the “BirthdayWisher_Table” and when the user is in the “Tasks_Activity” and press the Search menu item my app should search data from the “Tasks_Table”.

But it seems impossible to do so for me.

#### SearchAble Configuration file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/search_the_entire_app_"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.beaconimpex.assistant.app.ContentProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.Intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.beaconimpex.assistant.app.ContentProvider/BirthdayWishTable"
    android:searchSuggestPath="BirthdayWishTable"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" suggest_text_1 LIKE  ? "
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="1" >

</searchable>
```

#### Here is how i am associating my searchAble activity

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.beaconimpex.assistant.SearchAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_app" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

#### It is working very well for BirthdayWisherTable (because I have specified)

```
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.beaconimpex.assistant.app.ContentProvider/BirthdayWishTable"
android:searchSuggestPath="BirthdayWishTable"
```

#### My Content Provider

```
public class AssistantContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gcuf__dB";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 99;
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.beaconimpex.assistant.app.ContentProvider";

SQLiteDatabase db;
private DBOpenHelper dbHelper;

private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
        UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 12345;
static {    

    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BirthdayWisher.TABLE_NAME + "/"
            + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BirthdayWisher.TABLE_NAME + "/"
            + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);     
}
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "-----Query method is called with URI: "
            + uri.toString());

    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {       
    case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
        Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "URI Search Suggest");
        if (selectionArgs != null && selectionArgs.length > 0
                && selectionArgs[0].length() > 0) {
            // the entered text can be found in selectionArgs[0]
            // return a cursor with appropriate data
            return queryCursor(uri, BirthdayWisher.TABLE_NAME,
                    BirthdayWisher.allColumns, selection,
                    new String[] { "%" + selectionArgs[0].toLowerCase()
                            + "%" }, null);
        } else {
            // user hasn't entered anything
            // thus return a default cursor
            Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG,
                    "User has not entered anything in the searchBox.");
            return null;
        }

    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }



       }
}
```

**But how can i provide custom search suggestions for each Activity by fetching data from related tables using this method?**

Answer (score 8):

You simply need to add another searchable file. You can name it whatever you like, so since tasks is missing why not use `searchable_tasks.xml`?

Now copy all of the existing `searchable.xml` into this file, change the `searchSuggestPath` to `TasksTable` and do the same for `searchSuggestIntentData`.

Of course you have to expand your content provider as well (add those additional possibilities to the URIMatcher and react to the respective URIs in the query method).

Answer (score 2):

you should use the database join for all the table “BirthdayWisher_Table”, “Tasks_Table”, “Events_Table” and “BirthdayWisher_Activity”, “Tasks_Activity”, “Events_Activity” respectively to retrieve all table information. hope this [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm) could help you to understand what i am talking about. then you can parse all table information in search suggestion

another way to use AutoCompleteTextview

have a look on to this [source code](https://github.com/manishkpr/AndroidAutoCompleteTextViewExample/blob/master/AutoCompleteTextViewExample/src/com/manishkpr/autotextviewexample/SuggestionAdapter.java)

SuggestionAdapter class put the parameter "type" in constructor.

```
   String type;
   public SuggestionAdapter(Activity context, String nameFilter,String type) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.type=type;
    }
```

and then retrieve the information by type
on getFilter() method

```
List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions = db.getInformation(type)
```

then use the AutoCompleteTextView like following

```
  AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);

  acTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(this,acTextView.getText().toString(),"Tasks_Table"));
```

Comment: Using this method How can we identify in the `query` method of the Content Provider so that it checks that `BirthdayWisher_Table`, `Task_Table`, and `Events_Table` should be returnd ....

Comment: But i am using android.widget.SearchView in the ActionBar, As stated in the question i just want to know that Is it possible so that each Activity's SearchView menu show SearchSuggestions from different Database Tables. However if somone will give me a good reference that this is not possible so far, then i will look for a Customize solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If i am not wrong you can achieve this by:

Pass the activity name with intent to search Activity.
Get the called Activity Name from intent.
Now you have the called activity name , You can do whatever you want.

Comment: Actually this question is about search suggestion from multiple tables. And in case of search suggestion, `searchView` automatically calls the `query` method of my `contentProvider`, means we do not use intent for that.